# Flash ActionScript 2.0 problem with the object's _visible parameter

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-8

Hey guys, I've been trying to build something simple in Flash 8, and I stumbled across something weird I cannot explain:

I have an object, and at some point of the program, I want it to be visible (it is invisible at first), so I write:

```
_root.myObj._visible = true;
_root.gameOver.swapDepths(_root.getNextHighestDepth()); //so it will be on the top
```

and this works fine, the object becomes visible and etc.

What I planned to happen next is that the user presses a button on that same object, and the object will go invisible:

```
on(release)
{
 trace(_root.myObj._visible);
 _root.myObj._visible = false;
 trace(_root.myObj._visible);
 _root.gotoAndPlay("three");
}
```

The trace returns at first `true` and later on `false`, so the command works, but oddly the object stays visible, that's what I don't understand.

Thanks everybody in advance.

Comment: Is there some code on frame "three" that changes it back to visible?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the gotoAndPlay? If so, then your problem isn't with _visible, it's with whatever happens after the gotoAndPlay.

Comment: Yes, you are both right. But for some reason, even on onLoad() of the "three" frame it is already changing to visible,and there is nothing there that deals with myObj at all. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also put _root.myObj._visible = false; on the frame with your label of "three"